# Issue when install Sherlock

Tags: python, linux, installation

Trying to run Sherlock --help but when I enter the command I receive the following error:

```
File "sherlock.py", line 66
    Fore.GREEN + f"] {title}" +
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So I went back and installed the requirement.txt and received this:

This backport is meant only for Python 2.
    It does not work on Python 3, and Python 3 users do not need it as the concurrent.futures package is available in the standard library.
    For projects that work on both Python 2 and 3, the dependency needs to be conditional on the Python version, like so:

```
 extras_require={':python_version == "2.7"': ['futures']}

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-eb568s2s/futures/
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Checked to see what pip version I have installed, an in fact I have 20.0.2

Does anyone have advice about how I can get past this?

Comment: The `sherlock.py` file you are importing is for Python 3.6 or later. It has syntax that is new in Python 3.6. The syntax error is because you are running it under an earlier version. It is likely that you have two different versions of Python installed, each with its own version of `pip`. This is easier to do without meaning to than you might imagine.

Comment: Got it... "pip install --upgrade pip"  and when trying to access the program I needed to specify the Python version, i.e. 'Python3.8' ...NOT JUST...' Python3'!   Thanks for the assistance.